# Type hint from parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

How can you hint a class from the parent class like this?

```
class Cls1:
    class Cls2:
        p2: int

    class Cls3:
        p3: Cls2  # undefined name 'Cls2'

    class Cls4:
        p4: Cls2  # undefined name 'Cls2'
```

Comment: That would be nested class, not "parent class". And no you can't reference the parent class directly unless you do inside a method as it would haven't instantiated by then.

Comment: I assume that the `<<<` is meant to indicate the error on that line; I’ve edited it accordingly, please revert if otherwise @Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [PEP 484 §Forward References](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that
>   definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a
>   container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature
>   of some of the methods.

So, in your example, reference the not-yet-defined type in a string:

```
class Cls1:
    class Cls2:
        p2: int

    class Cls3:
        p3: 'Cls2'

    class Cls4:
        p4: 'Cls2'
```

Note that, while Python is happy to accept the above, mypy (v0.641), seems to have a bug and can’t find `Cls2`.

Comment: @Chris Well, did this answer your question? Don’t forget to [upvote/accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/158402) `:)`